ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cext: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
Hi i am having the following issue when I am trying to use matplotlib  on windows 10.
I have tried also the below but nothing helped:
pip install --force-reinstall pywin32
pip install --upgrade pywin32
py -m pip install msvc-runtime

any ideas?
import datetime as dt 
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib import style

"
Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\Users\ioann\OneDrive\Desktop\MISC\Stock Market training\main.py", line 3, in from matplotlib import pyplot as plt File "C:\Users\ioann\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib_init_.py", line 263, in check_versions() ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^ File "C:\Users\ioann\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib_init.py", line 257, in check_versions module = importlib.import_module(modname) File "C:\Users\ioann\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\importlib_init.py", line 88, in import_module return _bootstrap.gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\ioann\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\kiwisolver_init.py", line 8, in from ._cext import ( ...<8 lines>... ) ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cext: %1 is not a valid Win32 application."

Fixed by installing this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170
